# I need to deploy report from one org to onother org and need to schedule those report

Tags: reporting, deployment, dashboard

I am not able to identify the way to push report(report run/dashboard/snapshots) from one to other org.
I can see Eclipse is the one way and package deployment is other option.
I can use Eclipse but how can i Schedule those reports once pushed/inserted in the org.

Comment: Scheduling report would be a manual task after you deploy them.

Comment: I do have almost 500 reports.Is there any way to do it data loading or any other way

Comment: I am afraid, seems like there would be no other way.